# Why does my JavaScript onmouseover event not fire?

Tags: javascript, image, meteor, dom-events, onmouseover

In my Meteor app, I want to respond to an `onmouseover` event of an image and "pop out" the image (like a "zoom in") while the mouse is over it. I have this code:

HTML:

```
<template name="postTravelSection1">
  <div class="hide" id="postTSec1" name="postTSec1">
    <h2>Post-Travel Top</h2>
    <img id="imgPostTravelTop" name="imgPostTravelTop" src="images/1_PTE_Top_Jig.png" alt="post Travel image" height="280" width="350">
  </div>
</template>
```

CSS:

```
.popout_image{
    width: 400px;
    height: 320px;
}
.shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
Template.postTravelSection1.events({
  // 'onmouseover #imgPostTravelTop': function() {
  'click #imgPostTravelTop': function() {
    $('#imgPostTravelTop').addClass('popout_image');
    $('#imgPostTravelTop').addClass('shadow');
    $('#imgPostTravelTopRight').removeClass('popout_image');
    $('#imgPostTravelTopRight').removeClass('shadow');
    $('#imgPostTravelTopCenter').removeClass('popout_image');
    $('#imgPostTravelTopCenter').removeClass('shadow');
    $('#imgPostTravelTopBottom').removeClass('popout_image');
    $('#imgPostTravelTopBottom').removeClass('shadow');
  }
});
```

The `click` event works fine, but `onmouseover` (when I try to use that instead of `click` of course) does not fire. So how can I get a response to a `hover`, `enter`, or `mouseover` event on the image?

Comment: If you're trying to change the styling of a DOM object based on mouse *hover* [you can do that](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) 100% in CSS without any js whatsoever. Why do it the hard way?

Comment: I reckon so, but why is CSS preferable to JS?

Comment: So much simpler for starters! Plus it handles *mouseenter* and *mouseleave* automatically. And the cherry on top: faster.

Comment: Marischino (embalmed) cherries give me the fantods, but I get your point - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events you're looking for are `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. The available events are not very well documented on the Meteor website, but you can see a list of them in [this posting](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/8121695c963291946e40d27db0c02e604c0b8bbd/docs/client/basic/sections/templates.md) on Github.

```
Template.postTravelSection1.events({
  'mouseenter #imgPostTravelTop': function() {
    //enlarge the image
  },
  'mouseleave #imgPostTravelTop': function() {
    //shrink the image
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Brian's answer hit the nail on the head. Here is what works (just had to change the JavaScript):

```
Template.postTravelSection1.events({
  'mouseenter #imgPostTravelTop': function() {
    $('#imgPostTravelTop').addClass('popout_image');
    $('#imgPostTravelTop').addClass('shadow');
  },
  'mouseleave #imgPostTravelTop': function() {
    $('#imgPostTravelTop').removeClass('popout_image');
    $('#imgPostTravelTop').removeClass('shadow');
  }
});

Template.postTravelSection2.events({
  'mouseenter #imgPostTravelTopRight': function() {
   . . .
```